# ASP.NET Add HTML To Gridview header Text

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I.e. im wondering how i can achieve something like

```
<th><span>Discount</span>PLC</th>
```

In declaring a gridview columns such as

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Discount" HeaderStyle-Width="60px" SortExpression="discount">
  <ItemTemplate>   
    <asp:Label ID="DiscountField" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("discount").ToString() + "%" %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>                     
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How can I add this styling to the header text ?

Comment: Something some people may find useful - I needed to put a <br /> in some headertext and couldn't get it working with a TemplateField. So I just used &nbsp; for all the text except where I wanted the line break - and it worked perfectly. Could be an easy win depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 <asp:TemplateField >
        <HeaderTemplate>
             <span>Discount</span>
        </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>   
           <asp:Label ID="DiscountField" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("discount").ToString() + "%" %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>   

 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Make sure `<th />` is in context with the table.

Comment: I don't believe you want to put the <th> tags in that HeaderTemplate, because it puts whatever is in the template inside <th> tags already. So you'd end up with <th><th>xxx</th></th>.

Comment: Yeah It does seem to add <th> within <th> anyway around that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of  tag inside the header template.It will create a new heading.Template field is already creating a  tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of header tag inside the header template.It will create a new heading.Template field is already creating a header tag.